# AngularJS 1.2 Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: angularjs, cordova, steroids

I know it would be great if the file wouldn't link to local resource, but using phonegap/steroids framework, FILE_URI returns "file:///Users/" path which I can use for uploading to S3 or else, but Angular won't show it in the template.

Is there a possible solution? I tried adding config to my app

```
.config(function ($compileProvider){
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
  })
```

but it seems that doesn't have impact on the error.
I can base64 encode my images (then works), but I would like to avoid this if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Camera example in the [Steroids Kitchensink](https://github.com/appgyver/kitchensink) app, where the Cordova File API is used to move the picture from the `tmp` folder to the Steroids app's User Files folder. Since Steroids's `localhost` looks for assets both in the App folder and User Files folder, you can use an absolute path, e.g. `src="/my_image.png"`. See also the [App Structure on Device](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids-js/app-structure-on-device/) guide for more information on the App and User Files folder.